# How to pull reviews for business pages on facebook, not app pages, using the graph-api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, review

I am writing a site for a friend and would like to pull the business page reviews through the facebook api but everything I have found talks about it in the context of apps(which his isnt), not pages(which his is). Is it even possible to get these reviews through the graph api? Example is this site...

[Orion Off Road Reviews](https://www.facebook.com/pg/ORIONOFFROAD/reviews/?ref=page_internal)

Comment: Yes, you can get that from the API - but _using_ the API requires an app.

Comment: maybe Im just confused then. What is an app in facebook definition?

Comment: Anything that talks to the APIs is an app. You need to register one with Facebook, so you get an app id that the API can identify your app by. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register